# Split tab delimited column with space

Tags: unix, awk, command

I have following data in clicks detail file (clickInfo.txt) where there are 3 columns delimited by tab.
1st column represents count and productId separated by space.

```
101 111    productXyz      keyword1
 57 111    productXyz      keyword2
 12 222    product ABC12      keyword3
```

I have used following awk command to extract the 1st,2nd and 3rd column columns

```
 awk -F'\t' '{print $1 $2 $3 }' clicksInfo.txt
```

From first column I only want count and not product id like following:

```
101     productXyz      keyword1
 57     productXyz      keyword2
 12     product ABC12      keyword3
```

So how to split column(tab delimited) with space as delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` column 1 again with `space` and print the first part of it, try:

```
awk -F'\t' '{split($1, c, " "); print c[1] "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' clicksInfo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the space and everything after it—if any—in the first field (`$1`) with `""`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{sub(/ .*/,"",$1)}1' foo
101     productXyz      keyword1
57      productXyz      keyword2
12      product ABC12   keyword3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, assumes first column always has two columns of digits separated by space

```
$ sed -E 's/ *[0-9]+[ \t]*/\t/2' clicksInfo.txt 
101     productXyz      keyword1
 57     productXyz      keyword2
 12     product ABC12      keyword3
```

- `-E` use ERE, some `sed` versions need `-r` option instead
- `*` optional space
- `[0-9]+[ \t]*` one or more digits followed by optional space/tab
- `/\t/2` replace only second such occurrence with tab

Answer (score 0):

@Gunjan: @try: Though your question is not that clear, considering you need to get only very first column, then why not print only $1. Also if with space default delimiter itself we could do the task not sure about why it is necessary to make a tab as delimiter.

```
awk '{print $1}' Input_file
```

Comment: 1st column after using tab delimiter gives "count productId". Here count and productId are separated by space, so I need to first separate columns from clicksInfo.txt file,first by \t and then again split the 1st column by space delimeter to extract only "count".Does this makes sense now?

Comment: Could you please post your expected output with all your requirement details, sorry I didn't get it.